# How can I make an enemy ram through the player in Godot?

Tags: godot, gdscript

I'd like to make an enemy alternate between charging at the player and shooting at the player.

I can do this by using the move_toward() method and having the enemy stop at the player's position (for a given point in time).  However, I think it would be better if the enemy charged past the player's position.

[image]

This is the code I've tried for it:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    
    if shoot_on==false:
    

        position = position.move_toward(target, delta * speed)
    
    if position==target:
        shoot_on=true
        target = Vector2.ZERO
        $Timer.start()
        launch_proximity()


     func _on_Timer_timeout():
        movement_vector=(Global.player_pos-position).normalized()
    target=1.4*position.distance_to(Global.player_pos)*movement_vector
    shoot_on=false
```

I've omitted the launch_proximity() function.  It just fires a laser at the player.

This code makes the enemy alternate between its starting point and a point between the enemy and the player.

[image]

I can't figure out why.  Its motion is similar to what it did when I made the target

```
Global.player_pos-position.
```

I realised that this describes a point between the enemy and the player.  I thought I could fix it with

```
target=1.4*position.distance_to(Global.player_pos)*movement_vector
```

but the result is pretty much the same.

I've also tried

```
target=20*position.distance_to(Global.player_pos)*movement_vector
```

This will make the enemy charge past the player, but only a short distance.  Oddly enough, I get what looks like the same result when I use

```
target=2000*position.distance_to(Global.player_pos)*movement_vector
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  I'd like the enemy to charge further past the player, but altering the coefficient of the target doesn't seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 3):

This will be your mantra: REMEMBER THE DIRECTION, FORGET THE TARGET.

This seems to be your direction:

```
movement_vector=(Global.player_pos-position).normalized()
```

The line is equivalent to this:

```
movement_vector = position.direction_to(Global.player_pos)
```

*Note that here `position` is in local coordinates (coordinates relative to the parent node). I would suggest to work with global coordinates (`global_position`), and that would be extended to what you set to `Global.player_pos` wherever you set it. Anyway...*

Remember the direction. Make it a script level property. And you do not need to check `Global.player_pos` again. Forget about the target.

You will move with that direction:

```
position += movement_vector * speed * delta
```

*Or, again, work with `global_position` instead of `position`.*

See also [How to overshoot with direction_to](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/207043/10408).

---

For anybody doing this with a character body:

```
velocity = movement_vector * speed
move_and_slide()
```

*You would have to work with global coordinates, because `move_and_slide` works with global coordinates.*

People using character body might also be interested in: [How to move_and_slide to a target location and stop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77145466/402022) (which is the opposite problem than this).